# How to rewrite URL to reflect name of NLB not backends?

Tags: httpd, mod-ssl, nlb

I have a network load balancer in front of my httpd backends servers, but if I try to use write the name of NLB in the URL of my browser it'll redirect me to one backend, which is the goal, however, the url changes to the FQDN of backend.

Example:

URL: `https://<NLB>-webserver --> https://webserver1`

What I want:

URL: `https://<NLB>-webserver --> https://<NLB>-webserver`
To prevent users to get confused.

Is there a way for me to do this?

**NOTEL** I only have the capability of configuring DNS and the backend servers...